# Get layer type from layer in draw:deleted method

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I want to get the type of layer in draw:deleted method in leaflet.
Currently we can get it in draw:created method like this:-

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
});
```

I want to get the same inside draw:deleted method but we can only get the list of layers inside this :

```
map.on('draw:deleted', function(e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
           /*How to get layer type here? */
    });
});
```

One of a previous thread says we can apply the instanceof check. I tried the same. I want to perform this functionality for my custom marker , so i tried this :

```
L.Draw.myCustomMarker= L.Draw.Marker.extend({
    initialize : function(map, options) {
        this.type = 'myType';
        L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
    }
});

map.on('draw:deleted', function(e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Draw.myCustomMarker)
            alert("yes");
        else
            alert("no");
    });
});
```

This code fails. 
Kindly suggest how to get the type here?